Difference between "Schicksal" and "Vorsehung"
I've seen both being used seemingly interchangeably as translations of "fate" or "destiny". I know "Vorsehung" might be translated better as "providence", so perhaps it's more in the neighborhood of "divine will" than "fate", which can seem random. Is there any deeper meaning to either word that I'm not aware of?

Your question contains everything I would write in an answer :) Whether the difference "can seem random" is a question of theological beliefs, no linguistics involved. But that holds true for the difference between providence and fate in English just the same way.

"Vorsehung" is the verb-made-noun from "vorsehen", which means roughly "plan (to use)".1)

Dafür ist das X vorgesehen.
Wir sehen dafür Mittel vor.

For that X is planned (stipulated, allotted). and: We allocate funds for that.
In both cases we anticipate/foresee something to happen/be and make plans or reservations to deal accordingly with that.
So, "Vorsehung" contains indeed an element of will - planning, steering in some direction. The word is rarely used and when it is, then mostly in conjunction with something divine, e.g. "göttliche Vorsehung" - divine providence. God foresaw something to happen like it in fact did and provided some (counter-)measure to react to it in advance.
In contrast to that "Schicksal" (fate, destiny) also contains the notion of being unavoidable2), but not the will to steer things into a certain direction.
If you are to fall seriously ill then that might be called "Schicksal", but I'd suggest staying well clear from people calling such a fate "göttliche Vorsehung". Those are the ones lighting the stakes to express gods "infinite love for man" too.

1) @JonathanHerrera mentioned in a comment that "Vorsehung" is a word-by-word translation of Latin "providentia", which would not only explain the English translation "providence" but move it also in the direction of "provide". Neither the "Kluge" nor the "Pfeifer" are conclusive in this regard but it seems plausible. So, it might be that the verb "vorsehen" might in fact be derived from the noun "Vorsehung" and the  term "verb-made-noun" then would have a strictly morphological meaning as the "making" might be in fact the other way round.
2) Take greek (or Shakespearean) tragedies for instance: the outcome is preordained, but not necessarily so by a divine will. Rather, things are as they are and therefore a certain (tragic) outcome is unavoidable.

The etymology of Vorsehung is a little different. Although it looks like that from a mere morphological point of view, etymologically, Vorsehung is not the noun made from vorsehen, but it is the Germanization, the word-by-word translation of providentia. This also explains the semantic difference: the verb vorsehen cannot be used to indicate divine providence. See Pfeifer: https://www.dwds.de/wb/etymwb/sehen

@JonathanHerrera: hmm, the Kluge doesn't list it and Pfeifer only derives it from "sehen". Still, your derivation from "providentia" looks plausible (and I'd be interested in your source). Still, I'd hold that "vorsehen" and "Vorsehung" comes from the same source, most probably like "provide" too. If now "Vorsehung" bore "vorsehen" or the other way round is of little influence to my argument, no? Anyway, I tried to work your hint in.

I have to admit that I misremembered the Pfeifer article, which states that Vorsicht comes directly from providentia, but does not explicitly claim the same for Vorsehung. I am a little confused now by my false memory. I also remember a line in the libretto of J.S.Bach's cantata Schleicht, spielende Wellen: Die himmlische Vorsicht der ewigen Güte beschirme dein Leben, durchlauchter August. I always thought that Vorsicht means "providentia" here. But I also have to admit, that it could be different and it could simply mean "caution".

Anyway, I agree your argument is not affected by this, and I didn't mean to imply that.

Thanks. This is as I expected but I thought it was worth a discussion and the additional detail is helpful. For some extra context, I'm trying to watch "The Witcher" in German, and fate plays a huge role in the universe of the show. So it seems like every other sentence is "Schicksal this" or "Vorsehung that". I think in the show, fate could be spelled "Fate" and acts as a kind of deity determining events. This might mean that "Vorsehung" is used for "fate" more often than it would normally.
